# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql'

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I receive this "No Module named 'sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql' " error message when trying to run a new Flask project.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
  File "/Capstone/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from alembic import __version__ as __alembic_version__
  File "/Capstone/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import context  # noqa
  File "/Capstone/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/context.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .runtime.environment import EnvironmentContext
  File "/Capstone/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .migration import MigrationContext
  File "/Capstone/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .. import ddl
  File "/Capstone/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/ddl/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import postgresql  # noqa
  File "/Capstone/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/ddl/postgresql.py", line 8, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import BIGINT
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql'
```

app.py file:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, abort, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS
from models import setup_db, Provider, Patient
from auth import AuthError, requires_auth

def create_app(test_config=None):
  # create and configure the app
  app = Flask(__name__)
  setup_db(app)
  CORS(app)

  @app.route('/patients', methods=['GET'])
  @requires_auth('get:patients')
  def get_patients(token):
    ''' Retrieve Patients. '''
    try:
      patient_detail = list(map(Patient.format, Patient.query.all()))
      return jsonify({
        "success": True,
        "actors": patient_detail,
        "total_patients": len(Patient.query.all()),
      }), 200

    except Exception:
      abort(404)
          
  # @app.route('/coolkids')
  # def be_cool():
  #     return "Be cool, man, be coooool! You're almost a FSND grad!"

  return app

# APP = create_app()
app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
    # app.run()
```

models.py file:

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, ForeignKey, \
  create_engine
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
import json

# database_path = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
database_path = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')

db = SQLAlchemy()

'''
setup_db(app)
    binds a flask application and a SQLAlchemy service
'''
def setup_db(app, database_path=database_path):
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = database_path
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
    db.app = app
    db.init_app(app)
    db.create_all()

    migrate = Migrate(app, db)

# Goes on to define models
```

manage.py file:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import sqlalchemy
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

from app import app
from models import db

migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Lastly the pertient line in the source.sh file is:

```
export DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/capstone"
```

All three files are in the root directory. I believe I've downloaded all the appropriate packages to my requirements.txt file and used the proper imports. I deprecated Flask and Flask-Migrate on advice that didn't resolve the issue, but didn't appear to have a negative affect either. Any help is welcome. Thank you.

```
    alembic==1.6.5
    click==7.1.2
    Flask==1.1.4
    Flask-Cors==1.10.3
    Flask-Migrate==2.7.0
    Flask-Script==2.0.6
    Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
    greenlet==1.1.0
    gunicorn==20.1.0
    importlib-metadata==4.5.0
    itsdangerous==1.1.0
    Jinja2==2.11.3
    jose==1.0.0
    Mako==1.1.4
    MarkupSafe==2.0.1
    psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
    python-dateutil==2.8.1
    python-editor==1.0.4
    six==1.16.0
    SQLAlchemy==1.4.17
    typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
    Werkzeug==1.0.1
    zipp==3.4.1
```

Comment: Could it be related to this change [Remove support for deprecated engine URLs of the form postgres://; this has emitted a warning for many years and projects should be using postgresql://](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/changelog_14.html?highlight=postgres#change-3687655465c25a39b968b4f5f6e9170b)

Comment: Thank you, Van, I think it was related to that deprecation. I deprecated SQLAlchemy to version 1.23.3. And then I could move forward.